# Preencher ComboBox

Tags: c#, combobox

Em um Form Cadastro de Usuário, tenho uma combo box UF(que carrega os dados de uma tabela do sql), ao escrever na combox o sistema de precisa ir pesquisando os dados e apresentando apesar os que coincidem com o digitado. Estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
    private void carregaComboEstadoCivil()
    {
        ProfissionalBLL profissional = new ProfissionalBLL();
        profissional.carregaComboEstadoCivil(cbxEstadoCivil);

        cbxEstadoCivil.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(cbxEstadoCivil_KeyPress);
    }
```

Classe Profissional BLL

```
    public void carregaComboEstadoCivil(ComboBox combo)
    {
        FuncionsDAL carrega = new FuncionsDAL();
        DataTable tabela = carrega.listaEstadoCivil();

        DataRow linha = tabela.NewRow();

        combo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
        combo.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        combo.DataSource = tabela;
        combo.DisplayMember = "Descricao";
        combo.ValueMember = "ID";
        combo.Update();
        linha["ID"] = 0;
        linha["Descricao"] = "Selecione...";
        tabela.Rows.InsertAt(linha, 0);
    }
```

Evento do KeyPress

```
    private void cbxEstadoCivil_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        cbxEstadoCivil.DroppedDown = true;

    }
```

Porem não está dando certo.

A comboBox abre permite eu escrever mas não mostra apenas os registro que coincidem com o que eu escrevi ele me mostra todos os registro.

Comment: Poste a implementação do evento KeyPress, da maneira como está apenas carrega os dados.

Comment: private void cbxEstadoCivil_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        cbxEstadoCivil.DroppedDown = true;

    }

Comment: O que não está dando certo? Os dados não são mostrados na tela ou a busca não funciona?

Comment: A tela de busca não funciona!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    //criando palavras sugeridas
    var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    source.AddRange(new string[]
            {
                "Masculino",
                "Feminino",
                "Outro"
            });
    // criando combo
    var combobox = new ComboBox
    {
        AutoCompleteCustomSource = source,
        AutoCompleteMode =
            AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend,
        AutoCompleteSource =
            AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource,
        Location = new Point(20, 20),
        Width = ClientRectangle.Width - 40,
        Visible = true,
        DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
    };
    combobox.Items.Add("Masculino");
    combobox.Items.Add("Feminino");
    combobox.Items.Add("Outro");
```